# Kafka Avro deserializer is not able to deserialize the Kafka message of a specific Avro record

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform

I am trying to deserialize Avro messgaes that are in Kafka to POJOs generated from Avro schema. I am using `KafkaAvroDeserializer` for this conversion.

I am able to see the `GenericRecord` in the `ConsumerRecord<String, Data>` record returned from kafka. But when I try to assign this record to the generated POJO class object, it is failing for `date` type of POJO field with a `ClassCastException`.  When I checked the Avro payload this date field is coming in as `integer`.

Set up:

**Avro** - 1.9.1
**Confluent** - 5.4
**commercehub gradle plugin** 0.20.0

While trying to deserialze the Avro message, I am getting the error as:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 66
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.time.LocalDate
    at com.sample.Data.put(Data.java:229) ~[main/:na]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.setField(GenericData.java:795) ~[avro-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readField(SpecificDatumReader.java:139) ~[avro-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:237) ~[avro-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readRecord(SpecificDatumReader.java:123) ~[avro-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:170) ~[avro-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readField(SpecificDatumReader.java:136) ~[avro-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:237) ~[avro-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readRecord(SpecificDatumReader.java:123) ~[avro-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:170) ~[avro-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:151) ~[avro-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:144) ~[avro-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer$DeserializationContext.read(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:287) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-5.4.0.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:102) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-5.4.0.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:81) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-5.4.0.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(KafkaAvroDeserializer.java:55) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-5.4.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:60) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1310) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$3500(Fetcher.java:128) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1541) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.access$1700(Fetcher.java:1377) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:677) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:632) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1290) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1248) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1216) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1091) [spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1047) [spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:972) [spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_241]
```

Avro Schema of the field for which conversion is failing with `ClassCastException`

```json
{
    "name": "BIRTH_DT",
    "type": [
        "null",
        {
            "type": "int",
            "logicalType": "date"
        }
    ],
    "default": null
}
```

Code snippets from the generated POJO:

```java
  @Deprecated public java.time.LocalDate BIRTH_DT;

  // Used by DatumReader.  Applications should not call.
  @SuppressWarnings(value="unchecked")
  public void put(int field$, java.lang.Object value$) {
    switch (field$) {
    .
    .
    case 8: BIRTH_DT = (java.time.LocalDate)value$; break;
    default: throw new org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException("Bad index");
    }
  }

  public java.time.LocalDate getBIRTHDT() {
    return BIRTH_DT;
  }

  public void setBIRTHDT(java.time.LocalDate value) {
      this.BIRTH_DT = value;
  }
```

Kafka Consumer Method

```java
    @KafkaListener(topics = "${spring.kafka.consumer.properties.topic}",
                     groupId = "${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
    // Data is a POJO generated by Avro tools
    public void consume(ConsumerRecord<String, Data> record,
                        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) Integer partition,
                        @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) Long offset, Acknowledgment ack) throws IOException {
    
        logger.info(String.format("#### -> Consumed message -> partiion: %s, offset: %s", partition, offset));
        Data row = record.value();
        ack.acknowledge();
    }
```

build.gradle

```groovy
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter {
            url "https://nexus.abc.com:8443/content/repositories/jcenter/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.commercehub.gradle.plugin:gradle-avro-plugin:0.20.0"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.1.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
    id 'eclipse'
}

repositories {
    maven { url nexusPublicRepoURL }
    maven { url "https://nexus.abc.com:8443/content/repositories/confluence.io-maven/" }
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://nexus.abc.com:8443/content/repositories/jcenter/" }
}

group = 'com.abc.cscm'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '8'
targetCompatibility = '8'

ext {
    springCloudVersion = 'Hoxton.SR6'
    confluentVersion = '5.4.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'

    implementation "io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:${confluentVersion}"

    implementation 'org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.1'

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test'
}

springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

wrapper {
    distributionUrl = "https://nexus.abc.com:8443/service/local/repositories/thirdparty/content/org/gradle/gradle/6.5/gradle-6.5.zip"
}

apply plugin: "com.commercehub.gradle.plugin.avro"
apply plugin: 'idea'
```

`./gradlew dependencies --configuration compileClasspath` output:

```
> Task :dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

compileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
                        ** omiting spring deps
+--- io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:5.4.0
|    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.1
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.9 -> 2.11.0
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.9.3 -> 2.11.0 (*)
|    |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.19
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.30
|    +--- io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry-client:5.4.0
|    |    +--- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:5.4.0-ccs -> 2.5.0 (*)
|    |    +--- io.confluent:common-config:5.4.0
|    |    |    +--- io.confluent:common-utils:5.4.0
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.26 -> 1.7.30
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.26 -> 1.7.30
|    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.10.1 -> 2.11.0 (*)
|    |    +--- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:1.5.22
|    |    +--- io.swagger:swagger-core:1.5.3
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.2.1 -> 3.10
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.3 -> 1.7.30
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.5 -> 2.11.0
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.5 -> 2.11.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:2.4.5 -> 2.11.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.0
|    |    |    |    \--- joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.4.5 -> 2.11.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.26
|    |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.0
|    |    |    +--- io.swagger:swagger-models:1.5.3
|    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.5 -> 2.11.0
|    |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.3 -> 1.7.30
|    |    |    |    \--- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:1.5.3 -> 1.5.22
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0 -> 29.0-android
|    |    |         +--- com.google.guava:failureaccess:1.0.1
|    |    |         +--- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava
|    |    |         +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2
|    |    |         +--- org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:2.5.5
|    |    |         +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.4
|    |    |         \--- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:1.3
|    |    \--- io.confluent:common-utils:5.4.0 (*)
|    +--- io.confluent:common-config:5.4.0 (*)
|    \--- io.confluent:common-utils:5.4.0 (*)
\--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.1 (*)
```

`./gradlew buildEnvironment` output:

```
classpath
+--- com.commercehub.gradle.plugin:gradle-avro-plugin:0.20.0
|    \--- org.apache.avro:avro-compiler:1.9.2    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
|         +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.2
|         |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.2 -> 2.11.0
|         |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.2 -> 2.11.0
|         |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.11.0
|         |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.0
|         |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.19
|         |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.30
|         +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9 -> 3.10
|         +--- org.apache.velocity:velocity-engine-core:2.2
|         |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9 -> 3.10
|         |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
|         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.2 -> 2.11.0 (*)
|         +--- joda-time:joda-time:2.10.1
|         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.30
```

I am not sure if I should be editing my generated POJO class or if I am missing something.

I was able to convert an Avro message into POJO by changing the schema as mentioned in below question. But I think it is hacky and problem is not yet solved.

Question: [Avro is not able to deserialize Union with Logical Types in fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63642870/avro-is-not-able-to-deserialize-union-with-logical-types-in-fields)

Comment: Make sure your serializer and deserializer are using same date type object

Comment: Yes, same date type object is used for serialization and deserialization.

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody still encounters this error, there is a problem with the converter for logical types in unions and I didn't find a working avro version as of this date. It looks like the issue might be fixed by: https://github.com/apache/avro/pull/1721, but a new version still needs to be released.

I was able to fix my issue for the following field type
by setting the conversion manually

field type:

```
          "type": [
            "null",
            {
              "type": "long",
              "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
            }
```

setting the conversion:

```
ReflectData.get().addLogicalTypeConversion(new TimeConversions.TimestampMillisConversion());
```

and serialization/deserialization using the io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.ReflectionAvroSerde

Comment: avro just released it's `1.11.2` version two weeks ago where that PR was merged. Maybe your issue was solved https://github.com/apache/avro/releases/tag/release-1.11.2

Answer (score 0):

Could you please clarify what version of `avro-maven-plugin` are you using to generate the POJO ? As of avro version `1.9.0`, Joda-Time has been deprecated in favor of Java8 JSR310 and Java8 was set as default. See [Apache Avro 1.9.0 release notes](https://github.com/apache/avro/releases/tag/release-1.9.0).

When I generate a POJO from scratch, I get `java.time.LocalDate BIRTH_DT` and not `org.joda.time.LocalDate BIRTH_DT`.

```java
   @Deprecated public java.time.LocalDate BIRTH_DT;
```

So, in your case I think there is most likely an `avro` versions mismatch inside the classpath or a stale pojo. I would recommend verifying the avro version via `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.apache.avro:avro` call and regenerating POJO.

Comment: Could you please provide your gradle build file? thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am using com.commercehub.gradle.plugin:gradle-avro-plugin:0.20.0 which supports avro 1.9.0-1.9.2. Now, I have used gradle plugin , avro dependecy to match with confluent kafka avro deserializer 5.4.0. When I do ./gradlew dependencies --configuration compileClasspath. All avro dependencies are now at 1.9.1.  As you said, I have regenerated POJO and now BIRTH_DT column is showing as java.time.LocalDate. After running the error, I am still getting the class cast exception with this new type.

Comment: Ok, got it, thank you. Could you please also let me know, how the record got serialized before sending to kafka ? Is it also avro 1.9.0 library used for record serialization ?

Comment: I have updated question details with the new avro set up as you suggested. Also some output from gradle files are added. I have not investigated on how the records were writtent to kafka, I was thinking it should not matter as we have schemas. But let me check on that.

Comment: For serialization avro 1.8 is being used.

Comment: I think, avro 1.8 does not support proper Local Date serialization as it has been added in 1.9.0. Is it possible to upgrade the record producer to avro 1.9?

Comment: Sorry, we can't upgrade the producer.

Comment: Sorry, could you please clarify then how your kafka consumer gets configured? Does it read schema from schema registry ? If yes, is it possible to check the schema stored in schema registry ? Thank you

Comment: I've setup a local consumer/producer and it was able to deserialize LocalDate without the issue. I think, the issue can be with the actual schema taken into account by kafka consumer. So please give a hint of how the kafka consumer gets configured and what it the schema version used ? Could you please provide the source code or it's not possible ? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Mikalai. Did you take a look at the question link that I have added at the end. What I am seeing is, If a field has logical type and null in it, while generating avro classes  ,avro do not put proper Conversions in the class and then I get ClassCastExceptions for such fields. But when i update such fields schema and removes the null, avro puts proper conversions in the class and everything works fine. For your question, I have checked the schema that is being tagged to the record while i am in debug mode, Schema is same as the one that I have used for avro class generation.

Comment: Schema that I am using for avro class generation is downloaded from same Schema registry which i have configured in consumer config. I have used the latest schema version while downloading the schema for avro class generation. I am not able to provide source code due to restrictions. Thanks again.